# Ограничение по объему хранимых данных Vuex Store

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, vuex

Друзья, подскажите, есть ли какие-нибудь ограничения объема данных, которые можно постоянно держать в **Vuex Store**.
Отразиться ли на скорости работы браузера массив с 1000 объектов, состоящих из 5-6 реквизитов.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Отразится существенно, только если рендерить сразу всю 1000 элементов массива как список.
Рекомендую либо пагинацию, либо гуглить **vue virtual scroll**.
А если просто массив загрузить в память и периодически работать с ним, то 1000 элементов это мало, не почувствуете.

Comment: если при 1000 элементов в памяти браузер не тормозит, то при каких размерах массива, он начнет проседать? 10k, 100k? конечно же без вывода на экран

Comment: Очевидно, что все зависит от железа )) Что вам мешает создать массив нужного размера и протестировать производительность?

Comment: я думал, что может быть есть ограничения в браузере или общие рекомендации для хранилища Vuex. и спасибо за ответ!!

Comment: Тут стоит руководствоваться только здравым смыслом. Массив можете пихать любой, который в ОЗУ влезет )) *не надо*